# How to unit test a summation operation to ensure that the operation is actually summing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following property:

```
public double TotalHours
{
    get
    {
        return (from session in sessions
                let ts = session.End.Subtract(session.Start)
                select ts.TotalHours).Sum();
    }
}
```

The property should sum all hours done in all sessions.
What do I need to test in order to ensure that the property is always summing all the hours from all sessions?

Comment: What is `sessions`? Can it be set from outside the class?

Comment: sessions is an IEnumerable an object that has Start and End properties. It can be changed from outside the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically a case of working out appropriate sample data. For example, you might want to try tests for:

- No sessions
- A single session
- Multiple sessions
- Sessions with no start time or not end time
- A session where the end is before the start
- A session where the end equals the start

Maybe you've got other data validation to ensure that the "dodgy-sounding" situations don't occur, but those are the *kinds* of things I'd think about.

Comment: What about ensuring that start and end of all sessions are always fetched? Is that a valid test? Sample data does not guarantee summation.

Comment: @the_drow: Well if the sessions in a particular test all contribute to the sum, then if the result is accurate it's probably correct - it would be odd to have (say) sessions with durations of 1 hour, 5 hours and 4 hours and just *happen* to get a result of 14 hours despite having broken code, right?

Comment: While this is improbable someone might just write sessions[0] + sessions[1] + sessions[2].

Comment: @the_drow: And that would be caught by having a test with no sessions, and a test with just one session, etc. Ultimately your unit tests aren't going to *prove* your code works - they're just going to give you confidence. Give me any set of unit tests and I'm sure I could come up with a broken implementation which passes the tests - but that's not what happens in reality.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you mock your `Session`s to create the test data described by @Jon Skeet.  By using mocks, you isolate the code being tested to just the `TotalHours` property rather than the property and the implementation of `Session` as well.

Using [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), you could do the following to set up test data, call `TotalHours` and assert that the result is the value you expect:

```
var data = new List<ISession>
{
    Mock.Of<ISession>(s => s.Start == DateTime.Parse("12:00 AM") && s.End == DateTime.Parse("12:10 AM")),
    Mock.Of<ISession>(s => s.Start == DateTime.Parse("1:00 AM") && s.End == DateTime.Parse("1:15 AM")),
    Mock.Of<ISession>(s => s.Start == DateTime.Parse("2:00 AM") && s.End == DateTime.Parse("2:30 AM"))
};
```